# jQuery tool tip not working when images added dynamically using ajax?

Tags: jquery, tooltip

i am facing problem in jquery tool tip, when i am searching any image name and then loading ajax based search result in html then my tool tip is not working, even click event is not working.

same functionality is working in default image listing

can any one help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use .live() instead of .bind(). Read [this](http://api.jquery.com/live/).

> The .live() method is able to affect
>   elements that have not yet been added
>   to the DOM through the use of event
>   delegation: a handler bound to an
>   ancestor element is responsible for
>   events that are triggered on its
>   descendants. The handler passed to
>   .live()  is never bound to an element;
>   instead, .live() binds a special
>   handler to the root of the DOM tree.